# How do I create a list of 5 number permutations based on a list of numbers ranging from 1-69?

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, permutation

I have a SQL Server DB containing columns NM1-NM69 with their corresponding numbers in the field values:

```
NM1 | NM2 | NM3 | NM4 | NM5 |...... | NM69
------------------------------------------
1   | 2   | 3   | 4   | 5   |...... | 69
```

I am trying to figure out all 5 number permutations of this list. How do I do that in a simple and easy (well..easier) way?

example output:

```
PM NM1 | PM NM2 | PM NM3 | PM NM4 | PM NM5 |
--------------------------------------------
68     | 2      | 55     | 43     | 52     |
```

Edit: I'm using SQL

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Your output shows only one permutation of five numbers. Do you want to generate one permutation (at random?) or a table of all permutations?

Comment: @TedHopp A table of all 5 number permutations.

Comment: You do realize that table would contain 11,238,513 rows right? If you're fine with that. Unpivot the data and then cross join the result 5 times.

Comment: @Rabbit Yes, I will be filtering it against a couple tables that will hopefully bring it down into the 10,000 range. How would I cross join on 69 columns into 5?

Comment: You unpivot into 1 column then cross join 5 times. And I made a mistake earlier, there are many more permutations. I accidentally used the formula for combinations when I did the math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You UNPIVOT your data into one column and then CROSS JOIN five times. Here is a SQL Fiddle permuting 5 columns picking 3. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6378)

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Field1 INT, Field2 INT, Field3 INT, Field4 INT, Field5 INT)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1,2,3,4,5)

; WITH cte AS (
    SELECT u.FieldValue
    FROM @t
    UNPIVOT (
        [FieldValue] FOR [FieldName] IN (
            Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5
        )
    ) u
)

SELECT
    t1.FieldValue AS PermuteField1,
    t2.FieldValue AS PermuteField2,
    t3.FieldValue AS PermuteField3
FROM
    cte AS t1 CROSS JOIN
    cte AS t2 CROSS JOIN
    cte AS t3
WHERE
    t1.FieldValue <> t2.FieldValue AND
    t1.FieldValue <> t3.FieldValue AND
    t2.FieldValue <> t3.FieldValue
```