# Trouble with logic on how to query for all possible 5 number combinations of numbers 1 - 69 into SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm

EDIT: Just to clarify, the order of the results matters only in that 1,2,3,4,5 and 5,4,3,2,1 should be the same record. So I'm looking for distinct combinations.

I'm looking to build a SQL database with all possible 5 number combinations of numbers 1 - 69 where the same number cannot be used twice in a single 5 number combination. The result will contain 11,238,513 records. I'm having trouble writing the code to get this to work correctly with all logic at play. I've attempted a crazy macro in Excel VBA but I feel like SQL would have something simpler and quicker. I've asked something similar but it also just doesn't get me there ([How do I create a list of 5 number permutations based on a list of numbers ranging from 1-69?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401805/how-do-i-create-a-list-of-5-number-permutations-based-on-a-list-of-numbers-rangi)).

I've tried variations of below, but I just can't seem to conceptualize how I should be attacking this. Any help?

```
WITH range
AS (
SELECT num1 AS c FROM TEST1
  UNION  
  SELECT num2 FROM TEST1
  UNION  
  SELECT num3 FROM TEST1
  UNION  
  SELECT num4 FROM TEST1
  UNION  
  SELECT num5 FROM TEST1)
SELECT *
FROM range r1,range r2,range r3,range r4,range r5
where r1.c <> r2.c and r1.c<>r3.c and r1.c<>r4.c and r1.c<>r5.c
and r2.c <> r3.c and r2.c<>r4.c and r2.c<>r5.c
and r3.c<>r4.c and r3.c<>r5.c
and r4.c <> r5.c
order by r1.c, r2.c, r3.c, r4.c, r5.c
```

Comment: There is a simple solution. See my answer below. All other answers give wrong solutions, as they include permutations of each combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cartesian product the table to itself 5 times, and choose only rows where the numbers are in increasing order (this ensures the same number isn't selected more than once, and that there are no permutations of the same 5 numbers):

```
SELECT r1.c, r2.c, r3.c, r4.c, r5.c
FROM range r1, range r2, range r3, range r4, range r5
WHERE r1.c<r2.c AND r2.c<r3.c AND r3.c<r4.c AND r4.c<r5.c
```

Comment: btw, there are other ways to solve this.... hint: using LATERAL view subqueries.... but that's more complicated... and not supported in all databases....

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select r1.num1, r2.num1, r3.num1, r4.num1, r5.num1 
from TEST1 r1, TEST1 r2, TEST1 r3, TEST1 r4, TEST1 r5
where r1.num1 not in(r2.num1, r3.num1, r4.num1, r5.num1) and
r2.num1 not in(r3.num1, r4.num1, r5.num1) and
r3.num1 not in(r4.num1, r5.num1) and
r4.num1 not in(r5.num1)
order by r1.num1, r2.num1, r3.num1, r4.num1, r5.num1
```

By doing this you don't need to select the other columns, assuming that the rest of the columns have the same values.

In case the other columns(num2, num3, num4, num5) have other values, then you need this:

```
select r1.num1, r2.num2, r3.num3, r4.num4, r5.num5 
from TEST1 r1, TEST1 r2, TEST1 r3, TEST1 r4, TEST1 r5
where r1.num1 not in(r2.num2, r3.num3, r4.num4, r5.num5) and
r2.num2 not in(r3.num3, r4.num4, r5.num5) and
r3.num3 not in(r4.num4, r5.num5) and
r4.num4 not in(r5.num5)
order by r1.num1, r2.num2, r3.num3, r4.num4, r5.num5
```