# Sybase ASE 15.7 CTE to Subquery Issue

Tags: common-table-expression, temp-tables, sap-ase

This question is in regards to an earlier [post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230363/trouble-with-logic-on-how-to-query-for-all-possible-5-number-combinations-of-num) with code that I was running in SQL Server. I'm now using Sybase ASE 15.7 and am running into issues with the `CTE`. The error I'm getting is on the `WITH` part of the code below. I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803573/does-sybase-ase-12-5-support-common-table-expressions) which states to use subqueries, but isn't that what I'm using anyways? I'm not all that familiar with `CTE's`.

The only change I made between SQL Server and Sybase was that I am using a `temp table`, `#TEST1`, instead of a real `table`.

What do I need to change in order to get the query to work?

```
WITH range
AS (
SELECT NM1 AS c FROM #TEST1
  UNION  
  SELECT NM2 FROM #TEST1
  UNION  
  SELECT NM3 FROM #TEST1
  UNION  
  SELECT NM4 FROM #TEST1
  UNION  
  SELECT NM5 FROM #TEST1)
SELECT r1.c, r2.c, r3.c, r4.c, r5.c
FROM range r1, range r2, range r3, range r4, range r5
WHERE r1.c<r2.c AND r2.c<r3.c AND r3.c<r4.c AND r4.c<r5.c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pivoted the original table which allowed me to eliminate the `WITH` section of the code. And now it works!

Comment: CTEs are not supported in Sybase ASE, so indeed you need to rewrite the entire query.